# Which .NET frameworks versions does ASP.NET Core on .NET Framework (CLR) support

Tags: asp.net-core

**ASP.NET Core on .NET Core** is cross-platform ASP.NET. You can run an application written for .NET Core on Windows, Linux, and Mac. The server doesn't need the .NET framework installed.

However **ASP.NET Core on .NET Framework (CLR)** does require .net framework installed on your web server.

If I create a new ASP.NET Core on .NET Framework (CLR) template the default framework used is **.NET 4.52**

In the `project.json`

```
"frameworks": {
   "net452": { }
 },
```

If I change this value to later or earlier e.g.

```
"frameworks": {
   "net451": { }
 },
```

The project will support that version.

What range of versions does ASP.NET Core on .NET Framework (CLR) projects support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends highly on what you need and which packages you import.

[`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc/) for example depends on *.NETStandard 1.6* or *.NETFramework 4.5.1*. .NETStandard 1.6 is [included in .NET Framework 4.6.3](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md#mapping-the-net-platform-standard-to-platforms). So the lowest framework version that can run MVC is 4.5.1.

The packages have diffrent requirements, for example [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/) only requires *.NETStandard 1.3* which is supported by framework 4.6.

In general though, ASP.NET Core is built for the .NET Standard, and the lowest .NETStandard version that is supported by a .NET Framework version is 1.1 (with framework 4.5). I’m not aware of any ASP.NET Core package that only requires 1.1, so I think it’s a safe bet that you need at least 4.5.1 to run ASP.NET Core.

Every package has that alternate dependency on 4.5.1, so you *can* run the full system against that. You definitely cannot run it on earlier versions than 4.5 though.

Comment: You can find in [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/05/30/announcing-mstest-framework-support-for-net-core-rc2-asp-net-core-rc2/) that minimum supported version of desktop .NET is 4.5.1